# Save page as HTML dialog

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Is possible to show the `"Save page as"` dialog via Javascript?

I think that there must be such a browser function, at least for Chrome/Chromium.

If not, what are the alternatives?

When I say "Save page as" dialog I mean how to make the following window appear via Javascript (when pressing a button, for example).

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via JavaScript Strictly, **No.**

But here are two alternatives, 1 client side and 1 server side.

**Force Download via HTM5 link.**

> Now the
>   [HTML5](http://developers.whatwg.org/links.html#downloading-resources)
>   spec defines a very useful download attribute on hyperlinks that
>   basically allows to force download behavior on client-side, regardless
>   of what comes in Content-Type and Content-Disposition from the server.

Fiddled Here: http://jsfiddle.net/qmwxt/

`<a href="URL" download> Download your Question</a>`

Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970140/144665

**Set Content-Disposition in the header.**

Or if you have server side control set Content-Disposition in the header which forces the save dialog.

Read more here: [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Comment: The HTML5 solution sounds good. I will try it.

Comment: @Johnツ I thought it would fit your situation best.

Comment: @Johnツ So thats a new one for me so I had to see if it worked. And it does: http://jsfiddle.net/qmwxt/ Awesome!

Comment: That's really great. Can't understand why your answer is downvoted..

Comment: @Johnツ Revenge. Please up vote and accept accordingly.

Comment: I will accept and vote it in tomorrow, after testing. :-) Thanks!

Comment: But it doesn't address the problem of opening the dialog. Indeed to achieve exactly what he asked initially, the best alternative would be combine what I proposed below with this approach.

Comment: @SaulBerardo No dialog generated by JavaScript can direct a place on your hard drive to save a file in.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Now I got it.