# File/Save HTML documents after adding new text content, and persisting changes in the .html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on an on/offline text-editing HTML page to take notes. It has a `<textarea/>` like the [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page.

The problem is if the browser crashes, then some work may be irrecoverable. What is a simple, clean way to save the real-time contents of the HTML page to a .html file? In Chrome or IE is there *any* way to save the HTML document as it is exactly displayed?

I tried a `File...Save As` in Chrome and IE will not persist the text changes I made.

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486908/save-a-webpage-after-its-variables-have-been-changed looks similar, but is lengthy, and nobody answered it (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML/JS context in a browser runs in sandboxed mode, meaning that you can't read or write files programatically in JS directly to your filesystem. Take a look at [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) to check a way to do it indirectly (using browser abstractions). It's one of the most common ways of implementing persistence in an offline web application.

You'll probably find browser-specific functions that can make this, but I don't know of any portable solution for this that doesn't rely on plugins.

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501929/save-page-as-html-dialog), but I think you'll run in the same problem that you can't save the changes in the HTML structure and content

Comment: I don't know of web storage yet. W3C articles seem wordy to me, but you [second suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19502129/3266609) looks more approachable.

Comment: The W3C page contains the specification, it's kind of a heavy read :) Try [this tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/). Note that the second suggestion will probably only trigger the save dialog, so it won't be much different from what you have now (I haven't tested it though).