# use link to download json file

Tags: html, json

```
<a href="www.myfile.json" download>download file</a>
```

"www.myfile.json" is a link to a json file. My goal is when user clicks "download file", the json
file is downloaded automatically. However, with above code, when I click "download file", it opens 
the json file in browswer for me. I would like to know what I am doing wrong here.

I have tried the solution in this link([Chrome 65 blocks cross-origin <a download>. Client-side workaround to force download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down)), but I got Access to fetch at 'XXXXX' from origin 'XXXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. However, I do set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' in my request header. I am not able to modify anything on server side. What should be the right way to do for me?

My header looks like below:

```
headers: new Headers({
                 'Origin': location.origin,
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                 }),
                 mode: 'cors'
            })
```

Besides, I also tried set mode: 'no-cors', but it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force external download url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451720/force-external-download-url)

Comment: in what browser have you tried this? Check https://caniuse.com/#feat=download to see if the feature is supported in your browser.

Comment: I tried with chrome and it should work, but it did not.

Comment: Bear in mind that if the file in your hyperlink is not on the same domain as the webpage where the link is located, some browsers will ignore the "download" attribute. This is intended as a security feature, I believe. Chrome is one of those browsers - see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=714373

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down

Comment: I am currently working in local environment and the link is likely not the same domain.

Comment: "likely"? You surely must know already if it is the same domain or not? For example if you're running the site on `http://localhost` and the file is at `http://www.example.com/myfile.json` then clearly they are on different domains. However if the file is at `http://localhost/files/myfile.json` for example, then they are on the same domain.

Comment: Yes, they are not in the same domain. I am sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 65 blocks cross-origin <a download>. Client-side workaround to force download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474775/chrome-65-blocks-cross-origin-a-download-client-side-workaround-to-force-down)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will take a look. I also tried to download using firefox and edge and get the same experience.

Comment: Yes, Firefox also blocks the attribute on cross-origin links in the same way. IE doesn't support the attribute  at all, and mobile support is patchy (see the caniuse link above), so overall I wouldn't rely on the download attribute

Comment: The solution does not for work me. I got Access to fetch at 'XXXXX' from origin 'XXXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. However, I do set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' in my request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header needs to be in the response, not the request. You won't be able to read the response data without cooperation from the server.

So find a more cooperative server.

There's a [simple CORS proxy](https://bypasscors.herokuapp.com/) that will download any URL you give it, tack on the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and send it back to you. **If you're comfortable with a third party seeing the contents of your JSON file,** you can change the `fetch` line in the [linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500465/9029328) from

```
  fetch(url, {
```

to

```
  fetch(`https://bypasscors.herokuapp.com/api/?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`, {
```

Comment: I found we cannot use an unknown proxy.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to build your own server-side script that reads the file (with e.g., [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) in PHP, [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) in Python, [`http.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback) in Node.js) and echoes it back in the response. And when you do that, you can set the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header (again, in the response) and not worry about `download` and all the JavaScript.

Comment: When you say "not worry about download and all the JavaScript", do you mean I still need download attribute in my a tag, but no need fetch api call?

Comment: What I have tried is that set the Content-Disposition: attachment in header in response. In html, I have <a href="www.example.com/cross-origin-request" download>, but it still opens the request page for me not download any thing. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: If you don't control www.example.com, you aren't setting any headers in the response. Response headers come from the server; they can't be set from client-side code. If you do control www.example.com, `Content-Disposition: attachment` *should* start the download with just `<a href="//www.example.com/cross-origin-request">`. I don't know why it wouldn't.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!