# Cannot force download of external link

Tags: html, hyperlink, download

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451720/force-external-download-url), you can force the browser to download a resource instead of opening the resource.

However, it's not working for this link, which links to an Unsplash image:

```
<a id="dataFileLink" href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911164-1297abe8527c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" download="24.txt" style="">Download File</a>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6cp95ude/

Clicking the link doesn't force a download of the image; it merely opens the image for viewing.

Comment: `download` attribute only works on same-origin urls: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @mulsun please post as an answer so you can get credit. this explains why it didn't work. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`download` attribute only works on same-origin urls: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to tell your users to "Left click, download as, etc.", you could try something around the lines of the code below. However, I would research CORS before implementing this into your website to confirm it is secure for your use case.

```html
<script>
    function saveFile(url) {
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
        a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        delete a;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
    }
</script>

<a onclick="saveFile('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911164-1297abe8527c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80')">Download</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this.

```
`<a id="dataFileLink" href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911164-1297abe8527c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" download style="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556911164-1297abe8527c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Download Image">
</a>`
```

Comment: Read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212). Your HTML is [invalid](https://html5.validator.nu/). This answer doesn’t solve the problem.