# How to download video from external link instead of running it on Chrome

Tags: javascript, video, download

I'm having trouble downloading the video file
When you put the download link to mp4 video from an external link, what happens is that instead of downloading the file the video runs on Chrome,
Is there a solution to download the file directly instead of running it?
 The site where the mp4 file is is not mine

```html
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" download>download  </a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force external download url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451720/force-external-download-url)

Comment: It didn't work with me

Comment: the `download` attribute only works for assets on the same domain - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a ... possible solution would be a local handler to load the asset into a blob?